# rails cant create an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, creation

So I am making a colors palette manager and both tables requested on the form are nested and properly related(I would like to also point out that I am a rookie to rails)

This whole code was working perfectly fine when in line 4 was requesting links instead of just the names and suddenly wont work anymore, thank you for the help in advance

```
<div class='nav_bar'>#</div>
    <% if @projects %>
        <% @projects.each do |project| %>
            <li><div class='container'><h1><%= project.name project_path(:id => project.id) %></h1>
                <ul>
                    <%= form_for project do %>
                    <%= fields_for :palette, project.palette do |palette| %>

                      <%= palette.label 'background_dark_color' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :background_dark_color, placeholder: '@palette.background_dark_color' %><br/>

                      <%= palette.label 'background_light_color' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :background_light_color, placeholder: "@palette.background_light_color" %><br/>

                      <%= palette.label 'dark_color1' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :dark_color1, placeholder: "@palette.dark_color1" %><br/>

                      <%= palette.label 'dark_color2' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :dark_color2, placeholder: "@palette.dark_color2" %><br/>

                      <%= palette.label 'light_color1' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :light_color1, placeholder: "@palette.light_color1" %><br/>

                      <%= palette.label 'light_color2' %>:
                      <%= palette.text_field :light_color2, placeholder: "@palette.light_color2" %><br/>

                      <%= palette.submit %>

                      <%= link_to 'Destroy',  project,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

                    <% end %>
                    </div>
                </ul>

            <% end %></li>
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
    <div class='circle'><%= link_to "+", new_project_path %></div>
    <button type="button"><%= link_to "+", new_project_path %></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the following line,

```
<%= project.name project_path(:id => project.id) %>
```

There is a mistake in this code. There are two ways to fix this.

**Solution 1**

If you want to display a link or an anchor tag this use replace this with the following code,

```
<%= link_to project.name, project_path(:id => project.id) %>
```

**Solution 2**

If you don't want a link but, just the name to appear then, do the following,

```
<%= project.name %>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this actually fixed my problem, I do feel kinda foolish for not knowing this myself tho

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes and learn. Happy to have helped you.